# Can´t start Tor

Tags: windows, error, tor-install, support, log

I´m using a netbook with windows xp.
Here is the log:

```
7/25/2018 21:04:40 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
7/25/2018 21:04:40 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
7/25/2018 21:04:40 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
7/25/2018 21:04:40 PM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
7/25/2018 21:04:40 PM.800 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
7/25/2018 21:04:41 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
7/25/2018 21:04:42 PM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
7/25/2018 21:04:43 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection
7/25/2018 21:04:44 PM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus
7/25/2018 21:04:44 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus
7/25/2018 21:04:59 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors
7/25/2018 21:04:59 PM.500 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 3414/6374, and can only build 29% of likely paths. (We have 67% of guards bw, 62% of midpoint bw, and 70% of exit bw = 29% of path bw.)
7/25/2018 21:05:01 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 64%: Loading relay descriptors
7/25/2018 21:05:04 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 72%: Loading relay descriptors
7/25/2018 21:05:05 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 77%: Loading relay descriptors
7/25/2018 21:05:05 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
7/25/2018 21:05:05 PM.900 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:05 PM.900 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:06 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:06 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:07 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:07 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:08 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:08 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:09 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:09 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:10 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:10 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:11 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:11 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:12 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:12 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:13 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:13 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:14 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:14 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:15 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:15 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:16 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:16 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:17 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:17 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:18 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:18 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:19 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:19 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:20 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:20 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:21 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:21 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:22 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:22 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:23 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:23 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:24 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:24 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:25 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:25 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:26 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:26 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:27 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:27 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:28 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:28 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:29 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:29 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:30 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:30 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:31 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:31 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:32 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:05:32 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:01 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:03 PM.500 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:03 PM.500 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:03 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
7/25/2018 21:06:03 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:03 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:04 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:04 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:05 PM.200 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:05 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:05 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:06 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:06 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
7/25/2018 21:06:07 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but it seems like these lines at the start may be your problem.

> DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

To me, this sounds like it's blocking Tor's attempts to find the next hop. Someone correct me if that is a wrong assessment.